# Share a Photo On a Web-Service And Get The Public URL?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

I want to build an app in which the user chooses a gallery photo.

It then

1. uses "share via" to upload the photo from my device to any other 3rd party application that hosts files on the server.
2. then it saves the hoting url. Adds it to a UI list.

Are there any apps that retrieve the posting public url after the post is done - so I can use it in my app ?

Comment: You mean like the sharing button in the Gallery, and then share with your app?

Comment: Android "Share via" just shows you a list of applications (that you have installed on the device) that support sharing. Every application has it's own way of handling sharing, like for example Twitter application will upload your photo and tweet that. If you want to upload yourself to a service and get url then you have to implement that Webservice's API and upload your self and get URL.

Comment: isn't there an app which saves the photo online and then return the hosting url in OnActivityResult() ?